# how to include cropperjs library in rails6 using the webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, datamodel, cropperjs

I want to add the cropper functionality using the data modal, but I could not even select the file from the data modal.
I tried using the yarn install command and webpacker but javascript is not adding to the corresponding page.

Comment: To get the best help, please include relevant information such as the code you've used, versions of dependencies like webpacker, webpack, cropperjs, and any error messages you've encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `cropperjs` using yarn's `add` command and then import your necessary functions from the node_modules you have installed. Also, include CSS files from the node_modules, otherwise there might be some issues related to the styling.